# Replacing multiple characters using a mapping dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I'm working on harmonizing/cleaning a rather "dirty" dataset in Pandas. For the sake of demonstration, let's pretend it's this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"colname": ["ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ", "Ç", "ÈÉÊË", "ÌÍÎÏ", "Ð", "Ñ", "ÒÓÔÕÖ", "×", "Ø", "ÙÚÛÜ", "Ý", "Þ", "ß"]})

print(df)

    colname
0   ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ
1         Ç
2      ÈÉÊË
3      ÌÍÎÏ
4         Ð
5         Ñ
6     ÒÓÔÕÖ
7         ×
8         Ø
9      ÙÚÛÜ
10        Ý
11        Þ
12        ß
```

My goal is to clean the above column by applying the following mapping to the characters:

```
Before: ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß
After:  AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOO OUUUUY S
```

Although chaining 32 `str.replace()` should do the job, it doesn't seem like a particularly readable solution to me. E.g., for the first two:

`df["colname"] = df["colname"].str.replace("À", "A").str.replace("Á", "A")`

Instead, I was wondering if one could define the following mapping dictionary

```
sub_dict = {
    "À": "A", "Á": "A", "Â": "A", "Ã": "A", "Ä": "A", "Å": "A", "Æ": "A", "Ç": "C", 
    "È": "E", "É": "E", "Ê": "E", "Ë": "E", "Ì": "I", "Í": "I", "Î": "I", "Ï": "I",
    "Ð": "D", "Ñ": "N", "Ò": "O", "Ó": "O", "Ô": "O", "Õ": "O", "Ö": "O", "×": " ",
    "Ø": "O", "Ù": "U", "Ú": "U", "Û": "U", "Ü": "U", "Ý": "Y", "Þ": " ", "ß": "S"
}
```

and apply that mapping to the column of the DataFrame?

The cleaned output DataFrame should be the following:

```
    colname
0   AAAAAAA
1         C
2      EEEE
3      IIII
4         D
5         N
6     OOOOO
7          
8         O
9      UUUU
10        Y
11         
12        S
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that! Keep in mind there are important differences between builtin `replace()` and pandas [Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html). The latter one allows to pass a dictionary and perform multiple replacements at once. In conclusion, I recommend using pandas `Series.replace()` with your dictionaries:

```
df["colname"] = df["colname"].replace(sub_dict,regex=True)
```

Comment: This is neat haha, didn't know you can pass `regex=True` to `.replace`

Comment: Yes @Toukenize and it allows for a lot of more objects to be passed (lists, dicts), it is a lot more flexible imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a list of characters, explode the list, and apply the mapping `sub_dict` on each character, followed by grouping the characters again:

```
df_out = (
    df['colname']
    .apply(list)
    .explode()
    .map(sub_dict)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x : ''.join(x))
)
```

which gives you your intended output:

```
    colname
0   AAAAAAA
1   C
2   EEEE
3   IIII
4   D
5   N
6   OOOOO
7   
8   O
9   UUUU
10  Y
11  
12         # Check your mapping for "ß", which currently maps to " " instead of "S"
```